# Need "cd -" but for 3 directories

Tags: bash

I use "cd -" to jump back and forth between two directories.

Is there a command that will rotate between three directories?

Comment: If the directories you are using are static, you can just add a permanent alias to your `.bashrc` file. If you add a full path you can use simple commands to jump between the directories.

Answer (score 21):

There are commands (builtins) to maintain a stack of directories: `pushd` and `popd`.

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit more? Given that the user didn't find these 'simple' commands, I reckon there's more to it then just mentioning their name

Comment: use `man builtins` to get info on `pushd`, `popd`, and `dirs`. Set up convenient aliases to navigate. e.g. after 2 pushes, `pushd +1` will rotate through the 3 directories.

Answer (score 9):

`pushd` and `popd` can be used here, however unlike the former poster: see also [this howto](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/pushd_and_popd.shtml) once you have populated the `$DIRSTACK` with directories you can also use `dirs` and `cd ~1` to jump to  directories in `$DIRSTACK` directly!

Answer (score 3):

First add the second and third directories to the directory stack (your working directory is already in the stack).

```
pushd second/directory/path
pushd third/directory/path
```

Then rotate through your directories with the following command:

```
pushd +1
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is too obvious, open two or three terminals and run mc in them?

Answer (score 1):

pushd/popd and $DIRSTACK solutions proposed in other answers are the "canonical" way.

Another option would be to use [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) command. You open your directories in different sreens and switch between next/previous using [shortcuts](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Next-and-Previous.html#Next-and-Previous) - `Ctrl-a n` for next and `Ctrl-a p` for previous. Or using `Ctrl-a anyNumber` to go to a specific screen. Or using `Ctrl-a doublequote` to display and visually select which screen you want.

Check all possible [window navigation shortcuts](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Selecting.html#Selecting).

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'z' [link](https://github.com/rupa/z). It remember which directories you have been to and you can jump around with short commands and abbreviated directory names.

Answer (score 0):

like said before, but with just a little more words:

for **bash**, basically: instead of using cd use `pushd` to change directorys, so they are saved (meaning stacked)

```
pushd /home; pushd /var; pushd /log
```

To see the stack use `dirs` and for easier navigation (to get the numbers of the "stack-entries" use:

```
dirs -v
```

Output:

```
me@myhost:/home$ dirs -v
 0  /home
 1  /var
 2  /tmp
```

Now utilize these numbers with `cd` and `~` like:

```
cd ~1
```

But now these numbers are rearranged now and position "0" will change, so just `pushd` the directory to the top position twice (or use a dummy on position 0) like:

```
me@myhost:/home$ dirs -v
 0  /home
 1  /home
 2  /var
 3  /tmp
```

now 1..3 will keep there position
*I read this somewhere but do not know anymore, so sorry for not giving credit*

(to release the current directory from stack/deleting it from the "dirs"-history use `popd`)